# Chrome Extension for Third party Authentication

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying  to build extension for salesforce OAuth and invoking REST services from extension.

I searched for documentation and sample code for any third party authentication but not get any specific. 
I saw one YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQGjwsjtdwY) 
where they sown authentication with Instagram but not able to get source code for it and even tried to build it but not succeeded.

Is there any sample code for third party authentication?

Comment: get sample code on they doc  : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_auth_oauth.htm

Comment: The extension-native way would be to use [`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow).